# utf-8 encoding support in html file in glassfish

Tags: html, jsf, utf-8, glassfish

I have an HTML file in web-inf folder with Unicode characters. But when I run it, unrecognizable characters are shown in the browser, how do I get the Unicode characters shown when I run it?

I tried `<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>` but it didn't work, what could be the solution?

Comment: What have you tried ? Stack Overflow is not a free coding service.try to  Search and research and try writing some code. 
If you then have trouble, you can come back here and ask a proper question, providing [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

Add meta tag in head

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```